# How to get function value outside the function in python?

Tags: python

Code:

```
import logging

def main(name: str) -> str:
    return f"Hello {name}!"

print({name})
```

I wanna get main function output store in variable and use in outside the function. I'm new in python, I cannot see exact same example on net, Check multiple ways but not getting value.

There is no any value getting inside the  print({name}) or  print({main}).

Comment: `print(main(...))`?

Comment: `val = main('my_name')` will put the output of the function into the variable `val` - you can then print it afterwards with `print(val)`

Comment: print(main('testing'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def main(name: str) -> str:
    return f"Hello {name}!"

# You can use
print(main("world"))
# or
var = main("world")
print(var)
# or Under the current file
if __name__ == '__main__':
    var = main("world")
    print(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging

def main(name: str) -> str:
    return f"Hello {name}!"

return_value = main("your name")
```

To get a function's output you need to call it, and assign its return value to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

in order to call a function in python you must use its name no its arguments like below `main(f'{name}')` calls the function main with the `f'{name}'` as its argument.

```
import logging
name = 'world'
def main(name: str) -> str:
    return f"Hello {name}!"

print(main(f'{name}')) # If you just want to print it.

val = main(f'{name}') # If you want to store the output as[Guf] said.
```